# Sort WP posts by span value

Tags: posts, order

on website I have multiple posts that contains specific span. 
Example:
*Post 1: 4
Post 2: 3
Post 3: 7**

Is it possible to order posts by this span values?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be possible, or at least it won't be easy and efficient. Is there any chance that you could store content of that span as custom field?

Comment: If you have to sort them (i'm assuming this is front end sorting) by the content of a `<span>` then you're going to have to do it using javascript, which is a bit hacky.